# How to push a git ignored folder to a subtree branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a yeoman angular app and by default the dist folder came ignored. So when I try this: `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` it fails because it is ignored.
I don't want to push the dist folder to the master branch, I only want to push it to the gh-pages branch.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

I ended up writing a script for this. It creates a temporary commit with an updated `.gitignore` file with lines containing `gh-pages` removed.

After pushing the commit is discarded. The if statement is there so you don't accidentally lose work.

```
STATUS="$(git status)"

if [[ $STATUS == *"nothing to commit, working tree clean"* ]]
then
    sed -i "" '/gh-pages/d' ./.gitignore
    git add .
    git commit -m "Edit .gitignore to publish"
    git push origin `git subtree split --prefix gh-pages master`:gh-pages --force
    git reset HEAD~
    git checkout .gitignore
else
    echo "Need clean working directory to publish"
fi
```

---

<sup>Note that before v2.9.1, the status was `nothing to commit, working directory clean`</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Either you update the `.gitignore` file on the branch you want (preferred solution). Or `push --force` to force the update.

Comment: I don't have a local branch. It's like this:
root
  - src
  - dist
  - .gitignore

src folder compile files into dist folder. I don't have a gh-pages local branch, I push directly from master to gh-pages. But I don't want the dist folder to be included in master

Comment: Just update the `gh-pages` branch so that the `.gitignore` file does not contain the `dist` folder. Then create another commit with the files you need.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is here: https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/825950

The link above teaches you how to push your files to master, except dist folder; then, you simply navigate to your dist folder and, there, you push directly to your gh-pages branch.

Your question would achieve the perfect configuration, but i personally still prefer to use the traditional "remove dist from .gitignore" and run the git subtree command "git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages".

Now you make your decision!